# Conditions for $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} (\mathcal{L}f) (s) . (\mathcal{L}^{-1} g) (s) ds$

Tags: laplace-transform

Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) talks about suitable conditions for which the following formula holds good.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} (\mathcal{L}f) (s) . (\mathcal{L}^{-1} g) (s) ds$$

I am not able to understand the assumptions and conditions stated there. **Can someone please show with an example the cases where this formula cannot be applied?**

Comment: As they say, you need to be able to use Fubini's theorem for $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(s) g(x) e^{-sx} ds dx$. It's pretty standard to talk about cases where Fubini's theorem breaks down in analysis classes.

Comment: I admit I am totally unfamiliar with Fubini's theorem and spent a good deal of time chasing counter examples after seeing your comment. Almost all of the documentation I found on internet point to either some discontinuous functions or this particular one! - $\frac{(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{2}}$. From what little I understood, I am supposed to show that $|f(s) g(x) e^{-sx}| d(s,x)$ is integrable, but I don't know how I would do it without iterating the integrals on $s$ and $x$ (which needs Fubini's theorem to hold, chicken/egg!). Should I be using Green's theorem to convert it to a loop integral?

Comment: Also I am curious what the original Wiki page I linked to means by "under suitable assumptions on the behaviour of $f,g$ in a right neighbourhood of $0$ and on the decay rate of $f,g$ in a left neighbourhood of $\infty$" and whether there is a simpler way to check for Fubini's Theorem without actually evaluating the integral of the absolute function I mention above (in this special case involving LT).

Comment: Any example where it will break will have that the integral where $f$ and $g$ are replaced by $|f|$ and $|g|$ must blow up. Regarding your second comment, what they seem to be talking about is that you can get a sufficient condition having only to do with growth at $0$ and decay at $\infty$.